# Setting up nginx to stream HLS/RTMP simultaneously

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have an nginx web server with the RTMP module running perfectly and pushing out video to several RTMP destinations (Facebook, YouTube, Periscope, etc.).

I now need the stream to output in the HLS protocol so I can build a custom player for it without flash dependency. I've tried following a few other tutorials, but I am struggling.

I have the default config file that came with the installation of nginx with the following added to the end:

```
rtmp {
    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4096;

            application live {
                    live on;
                    record off;
                    push rtmp://<streaming-service/key>
            }
    }
}
```

What exactly do I need to add to this config file to retain my ability to push out video to these RTMP destinations as well as have a HLS feed I can use in a player without Flash?

I already have FFMPEG installed on the machine in order to send video to Periscope. I've seen solutions that do not need FFMPEG, but I just wanted to add that I did have it installed and am somewhat familiar with it.

EDIT: for more information, I am sending video through the server via a Teradek encoder.

Comment: I am wondering if I am just overthinking this and all I need to do is use the "pull" command to take my RTMP. Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with FFMPEG. The pull directive wasn't working properly. Here's the config file that worked for me:

```
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
            worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

   include   mime.types;

   default_type application/octet-stream;

   sendfile on;

     server {

            listen 80;

            server_name localhost;

   location /hls {

            types {

                       application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;

                      video/mp2t ts;
           }

           root /tmp/;

     add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

            }


location / {

           root   html;

           index  index.html index.htm;

           }

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

           location = /50x.html {

           root   html;

           }

}

}

rtmp {
   server {
           listen 1935;

           chunk_size 4096;

           application live {

                        live on;
                       record off;

                       push rtmp://<location/key>

                       exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/test -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -x264opts keyint=40 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/test;

           }

           application hls {

                       live on;
                       hls on;
                       hls_path /tmp/hls/;
                       hls_fragment 6s;
                       hls_playlist_length 60s;
                       }

   }
}
```